# API Instagram - Buscar fotos públicas por TAG

Tags: api, instagram-api

Estou querendo obter todas as fotos com uma HASHTAG especifica, porém ao usar a seguinte URL oferecida pela API do Instagram...

*

> `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

*

...simplesmente ele retorna as minhas fotos do meu perfil com a HASHTAG, como eu comecei a estudar ontem essa API, acredito que seja o ACCESS_TOKEN que está fazendo isso, já que existe um vinculo a minha conta, apenas suspeito, gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de capturar todas as fotos públicas com a Hashtag especifica, alguém poderia me ajudar?

...andei lendo que a API teve algumas mudanças permitindo somente o acesso as fotos sem ser do FEED, porém encontrei um aplicativo para desktop que faz de tudo um pouco, o nome de é 4K Stogram, como é possível isso? No caso quero fazer a mesma coisa...

https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-stogram

Answer (score 1):

O *endpoint* que você está procurando é esse:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação oficial da API do Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/).

Comment: Usei uma hashtag especifica e ele só retornou 12 resultados do meu próprio perfil, no caso eu queria resultados públicos com aquela HASHTAG... fiz um teste com uma tag inexistente no meu perfil e retorna isso: {"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}

Comment: Você está fazendo a pesquisa no sandbox ou fora dele?